# How to Get Reference to Document Array from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is the structure of my Firestore data right now:

[image]

I'm having trouble just accessing the `favourites` array. I seem to be accessing the collection and document just fine, but I can't seem to pull the favourites array in my code.

This is the relevant code in my data model

```
protocol UserFavouritesProtocol {
    
    func userFavouritesRetrieved(userFavourites:[UserFavourites])
    
}

var delegateTest:UserFavouritesProtocol?
    
    func getFavourites() {
        
        // Detach any listener
        listener?.remove()
        
        // Get a reference to the database
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        var query:Query = db.collection("userFavourites")
        
        self.listener = query.addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
            
            // Check for errors
            if error == nil && snapshot != nil {
                
                var userFavourites = [UserFavourites]()
                
                // Parse documents into mealPlans
                for doc in snapshot!.documents {
                    
                    let u = UserFavourites(
                        favouriteMealPlans: doc["favourites"] as? [String])

                    userFavourites.append(u)
                }
                
                // Call the delegate and pass back the notes in the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.delegateTest?.userFavouritesRetrieved(userFavourites: userFavourites)
                }
                
                
            }
            
        })
        
    }
```

This is my `UserFavourites` struct:

```
struct UserFavourites {
    
    var favouriteMealPlans:[String]?
    
}
```

At this point, how can I access the `favourites` array and call a reference to it? For example, I later want to see if a particular string is contained within my `favourites` array.

Comment: You don't appear to be doing anything with `u` once you create it. Do you mean to be adding it to the `userFavourites` array?

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for catching that! I accidentally excluded it when I was cleaning up my question. Edited the question now.

Comment: What happens when you print `doc.data()` right before your `let u` line?

Comment: @jnpdx I get the following in the console: `["favourites": <__NSArrayM 0x600000c02940>(
mp00002,
mp00004
)
]`

Comment: Instead of using as? to cast to String, try using as! and see if you get a runtime error, that would mean that the result you are getting cannot be casted to a String

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012956/firestore-how-to-store-reference-to-document-how-to-retrieve-it) will get you closer to your solution...

```swift
// struct
import FirebaseFirestore
struct UserFavourites {
    var favouriteMealPlans:[DocumentReference]?
}
```

```swift
// usage
let u = UserFavourites(favouriteMealPlans: doc["favourites"] as? [DocumentReference])
```