# how to initialize DocumentReference type inside Interface of Typescript of Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Thank you for reading my question.

Program: Angular 13, Firestore  v9 database and firebase Authentication.

When someone sings-up via Firestore Authentification.

I send user typed-information from a form (Name, address and others) along with initial values for user account.

like this below,

`this.usersService.addUser({ uid, email, firstName, lastName, uidRole, companyRef });`

this is my ProfileUser

```
export interface ProfileUser {
uid?: string;
email?:string;
firstName?:string;
lastName?:string;
uidRole?:string;
companyRef?: DocumentReference;
}
```

Just before excute this.sersService.addUser(), I initialize some information.
For example

this works fine:
`let uidRold: string = 'USER'`

but this line throws error:
`let companyRef: DocumentReference = 'any/string/'`
because it is not initialized. The firestore requres inital value for companyRef.

How can I initialize "companyRef" manually prior to this command below?

`this.usersService.addUser({ uid, email, firstName, lastName, uidRole, companyRef });`

I appreciate your help.

my first thought:
I have not found any similar cases online yet. Should i get a dummy documentreference and put it in?

another though:
I want to just type casting from a string of "examplecollection/document" to DocumentReference type? then, in this case, i have not figured out how to type casting from string to DocumentReference type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this for your user profile model/interface:

```
export interface ProfileUser {
uid?: string;
email?:string;
firstName?:string;
lastName?:string;
uidRole?:string;
companyRef?: DocumentReference | null; //<--- add '| null' here
}
```

This could also help [Firestore how to store reference to document / how to retrieve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50012956/firestore-how-to-store-reference-to-document-how-to-retrieve-it)

Comment: I have added null.  but still it says "ERROR FirebaseError: Function setDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined. I think when i call the function with companyRef. I declare like this:  let myChurchRef: DocumentReference; then call:  this.usersService.addUser({ uid, email, firstName, lastName, uidRole, companyRef });

it adds User without companyRef as a parameter. but with companyRef, it show the above error.

Comment: I appreciate your comment by the way. Werner7..

Comment: Maybe do a check if CompanyRef is undefined/null before adding a new user and then omit it if it is? Set your companyRef as an option parameter maybe? If you post more of code it might helpful, it's a little hard for me to get my head around what's happening with what's provided.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just did not initialise it because in interface i put it as optional with "?". Hence, whenever i need, i created it in Firebase. It worked fine. Noerror. Thank you again. I wished that like const or string variables, you can initialise its first value. But if this does not need to be initialused, i think it is also fine. No errors.